# Building qtcreator project using docker

Tags: linux, macos, docker, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I would like to know if someone already succeed to build (and debug) a qtcreator project using docker?
I am developping a linux application on MacOS. For now, I'm programming using QtCreator on MacOS then I compile and test in a docker shell (I am sharing the project source between MacOs and the docker container with docker-sync). But it is not very practical so if anyone has a better solution for me...

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental docker plugin that you can enable. It allows you to directly create a Docker device and Kit that compiles and runs your project in a docker container. It's very experimental right now though. The next major update (8.0) will bring significant improvements to it.